# Is there a way to find out what interfaces my struct implements either through go cmdline or IDE (IntelliJ)?

Tags: go

Say I have

```
// main.go
type Speaker interface {
  Speak()
}

type Person struct {}

func (p *Person) Speak() {
   panic("test")
}
```

Given a person elsewhere in the code is there a way to tell what interfaces Person implements? Here it's clear Person implements Speaker but what if another type

```
type Ghost interface {
  Speak()
}
```

existed in another package?

For context, I'm looking through a codebase and am having difficulty deciding if it's ok to delete a receiver method because it's difficult to tell if the method exists to meet an interface requirement or is simply augmenting functionality. In a self contained codebase I can delete it and see if a compiler error comes up but I cannot do the same in a common library.

Comment: If you use IntelliJ, How about Cmd + U? It goes to the super method, such as interface
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the goland documentation, you can go to a single implementation with the gutter icon that is implementing or overriding your interface or you can find out all the implentations by using Cmd + U (assuming your working from a Mac). here is a link to the documentation:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_implementation

Since Goland is a Go IDE based from IntelliJ you should be able to do the same thing. you may need to configure the gutter icons but the same command should work in IntelliJ.